# what is the min open cv version that takes Rect object to draw a rectangle

Tags: opencv, rect

I am currently using  cv 3.4 my existing code with open cv4  used Rect object to draw a rectangle , when i downgraded , to draw a rectangle we require two points , is there any way in which i can use Rect object to draw rectangle using a Rect object in opencv 3 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can draw a rectangle given a cv::Rect at least from version 2.3, always with `cv::rectangle(...)`. Some code to explain your actual problem would be helpful

Comment: He means using cv2.rectangle() with Rect in python still not available in 3.X

Answer (score 0):

it is only available in 4.X unfortunately [ABI](https://abi-laboratory.pro/?view=timeline&l=opencv) (backward compatibility policy) did not allow to fix this in 3.X

see the code on [3.4 branch](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp#L1844-L1854) and [master branch](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp#L1862-L1871)